Is FM ever used for digital radio transmission
The idea would be to transmit multiple bits(or frames) with each cycle of the RF oscillator. So you would use a 64-bit DAC to convert the digital data stream into an analog signal, frequency modulate it, and then transmit it. Why FM? Because it has much larger bandwidth. The receiver would demodulate the signal and then convert it back into a digital stream. Do systems like this exist and have they been tried?

There is RDS protocol used to transmit text over FM.

"larger bandwidth"... than what?

64-bit DAC? Where can I get one of those?

@JohnDoty I don't care, as long as you don't operate it while I'm close by and not being a wall of sand bags. (say, the smallest possible value that this DAC outputs is 1 pV = 10⁻¹² V, which is far less than even theoretically possible, then the largest value would be somewhat like 18 MV, which of course is something I'm not exactly keen on standing next to)

Yes, extracting high-speed data (many Mbps) from rotating equipment that is battery powered is one definite area I've worked with before. However, there is no real single answer to this question and that is why I'm not making a formal answer.

Sure, there's a lot of amateur radio modes that are horribly inefficient that do AFSK and similar things in the FM data. As mentioned in the comments, there's also RDS, which is PSK modulated onto an above-audible carrier that you get after FM demodulation.
And of course, there's FSK, which is really widely used, which is just FM with discrete possible frequencies.

So you would use a 64-bit DAC to convert the digital data stream into an analog signal, frequency modulate it, and then transmit it. Why FM? Because it has much larger bandwidth.

What you describe would be a 264-FSK. That doesn't work, you don't get that kind of SNR in the real, physical world, so that this would come close to making sense for transporting any measurable amount of information (and I mean that, you literally won't get your 64 bits across, because noise will fundamentally not allow you to resolve these many bits).
Also "much larger bandwidth": um, than what? And: "large bandwidth" is the opposite of what you want as communications engineer; it means that you get all the noise from the large bandwidth, and need all the spectrum for one communication channel. You want as little bandwidth as possible for your desired data rate. That is the usual optimization goal.
Generally, frequency modulation modes don't have extremely high spectral efficiency: You really might want to look up this term!

and have they been tried?

Most basic modulation things that aren't inherently bad have been mathematically exhaustively investigated. FM is over 80 years old by now!
In the case of your question, things make little to no sense: you need a receiver to be able to tell 264 different frequencies apart. We can actually put a hard physical lower limit on how long you need to observe a signal to be able to do that, it's Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. In the case of FSK, it's got a pretty simple result: for every bit that you give your DAC that you want to be able to make out at the receiver, you will need to double the duration of your symbol. So, not a great deal at all!
I feel like you're coming from a different background than me, and that's fine. You'll want to learn a bit about the basics of wireless communication of data, and how we can, sometimes quite easily, sometimes not, quantify things like "is this a good idea on how to bring data on the air?".
You are, however, on a website for electrical engineers. So, you're asking on the level of someone who, at least in the long past, has gone through the math an EE student has gone through. So, Software-Defined Radio for Engineers (PDF) by by Travis F. Collins, Robin Getz, et al, should be quite up your alley.
Don't skip the first 3 chapters! They should be a not-too-hard entry, and you'll definitely need them to understand chapter 4, Digital Communications Basics, on a level that is more than "oh yes, these are pretty pictures".
